# Is "docker-compose up" atomic?

Tags: makefile, docker-compose, atomic

I have just reviewed a PR with the following `||` operator in a Makefile:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --scale worker=3 \
    || docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down ; false)
```

The rationale is that if `docker-compose up` fails, `docker-compose down` will clean up any unnecessary running containers.

However, if `docker-compose up` is atomic, this is probably unnecessary.

**Is `docker-compose up` atomic, meaning either all planned containers, or none, are running after its invocation?**

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't atomic. Spare containers may be still running.

A simple `CTRL+C` test solved the problem. `docker-compose up` exited and some containers are running.